# Data Table Manipulation in Mathematica: Step 2

Tags: list-manipulation

In this previous post ([Data Table Manipulation in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29334/5)) we find the brilliant suggestion proposed by Leonid Shifrin that allows to select specific rows identified by the header name.

I'm now looking for a way to then also select the data of a specific column (or more columns) of the subset of data generated by Leonid's select function.

Suppose we have this data:

```
table = List[
{"ID", "Variable 1", "Variable 2"}, 
{"Alpha", 1, 0}, 
{"Beta", 1, 1}, 
{"Alpha", 0, 0}]
```

which when formatted as a grid looks like this:

```
ID     Variable 1 Variable 2
Alpha       1          0
Beta        1          1
Alpha       0          0
```

Using Leonid's function we can obtain this:

```
subset = select[table, where["Variable 1" == 1]]

(* {{"Alpha", 1, 0}, {"Beta", 1, 1}} *)
```

Suppose that we now want to sum all the values that are in the column named 'Variable 2'. We could just do this:

```
Total[subset[[All,3]]]
```

However, in this way we loose the advantage of using Leonid's function that can work directly with header names. Ideally, I would like to find a way to get those data by using the header name. Something like:

```
Total[subset[[All,"Variable 2"]]]
```

or, even better:

```
select[table, where["Variable 1" == 1], columns["Variable 2"]]
```

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This modification of `select` should do what you ask, while keeping the previous functionality:

```
ClearAll[select, where];
SetAttributes[where, HoldAll];
select[table : {colNames_List, rows__List}, where[condition_], 
    cols : (columns[varNames__] | All) : All] :=
   With[{namingRules = 
      Dispatch[Thread[colNames -> Thread[Slot[Range[Length[colNames]]]]]]},
      With[{selF = Apply[Function, Hold[condition] /. namingRules], 
         cl = {varNames} /. namingRules /. Verbatim[Slot][n_] :> n},
          If[cols ===  All, #, #[[All, cl ]]] &@Select[{rows}, selF @@ # &]]];
```

For example,

```
select[table,where["Variable 1"==1],columns["Variable 1"]]
(* {{1},{1}} *)

select[table,where["Variable 1"==1],columns["Variable 2","Variable 1"]]
(* {{0,1},{1,1}} *)

select[table,where["Variable 1"==1]]
(* {{Alpha,1,0},{Beta,1,1}} *)
```

You can also use the plain column numbers in `columns`:

```
select[table,where["Variable 1"==1],columns[3,2]]
(* {{0,1},{1,1}} *)
```

or a mix:

```
select[table,where["Variable 1"==1],columns[3,"Variable 1"]]
(* {{0,1},{1,1}} *)
```

**EDIT**

Per request of @Viktor, expressed in comments, here is a generalization of `select` where the `where` clause is made optional as well:

```
ClearAll[select, where];
SetAttributes[where, HoldAll];
select[table : {colNames_List, rows__List}, w : (where[condition_] | None) : None,
     cols : (columns[varNames__] | All) : All] :=
  With[{namingRules = Dispatch[Thread[colNames -> Thread[Slot[Range[Length[colNames]]]]]]}, 
    With[{cl = {varNames} /. namingRules /. Verbatim[Slot][n_] :> n},
      If[cols === All, #, #[[All, cl]]] &@
        If[w === None,
           {rows},
           (* else *)
           With[{selF = Apply[Function, Hold[condition] /. namingRules]},
              Select[{rows}, selF @@ # &]
           ]
        ]
    ]
  ];
```

For example, in addition to the previous inputs, we may enter:

```
select[table,columns["Variable 1"]]
(* {{1},{1},{0}} *)
```

Comment: +1 Perhaps you should mention that this version also allows the use of raw column numbers (the `Slot` part of your code).

Comment: @Sjoerd True, I meant this, but then had a second thought that this might not be a good style, so did not mention that. Perhaps better to mention. Will edit.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Viktor Glad I could help. I actually liked these questions because these are good and small examples of putting meta-programming (construction of a function programmatically and at run-time) to do some real non-trivial work that makes our life easier.

Comment: Another idea is to extend this to arbitrary transformations, analogously to the `Cases[table, pattern -> transformation]` syntax (see my asnwer).  Nice idea to come up with this notation, BTW, +1

Comment: I have a suggestion for an additional improvement. Right now in the above function the 'columns' argument is optional, but the 'where' argument is not. It might be useful to make also the 'where'  argument optional. In this way it would be possible to use this function to extract all the elements of a column by using the header name. Unfortunately, it seems that I'm not able to adapt the function to fulfill also this capability.

Comment: @Viktor Please see my edit

Comment: Great. I think that this function should be included by default in Mathematica, it makes data manipulation clear and easy. Thanks Leonid.

Answer (score 9):

<sub>I had to leave just when you posted the question, so I'm a little late, but here's my implementation anyway.</sub>

When I read your question, I saw

```
Cases[table, {id_, var1_, var2_} /; var1 == 1 -> var2]
```

What you require is not to have to write out the full row pattern, but to be able to refer to row items by names.  Here's my implementation for that.  It should be easy to understand and modify if you so desire.

```
SetAttributes[namedCases, HoldRest]

namedCases[{head_, rows___}, condition_, transform_] := 
  With[
  {headPatt = Pattern[#, _] & /@ head, 
   patternNames = Table[Unique[h], {Length[head]}]
  }, 
  SetAttributes[patternNames, Temporary]; (* avoid name pollution *)
  Module[{r = {rows}}, 
    Unevaluated@Cases[r, headPatt /; condition :> transform] /. 
        Thread[head -> patternNames]
  ]
]
```

<sup>Note: I used `Module` to avoid replacement inside the table (not header).</sup>

It was my aim to make this as easily modifyable as possible, if you want to extend this way of working with tables to other operations.  You can do a lot by only changing the `Cases[]` line to something else.

Here I am assuming that your header consists of strings only, not symbols or numbers.  Otherwise this function may need to be strengthened to avoid unexpected breakage.

Usage:

```
namedCases[table, "Variable 1" == 1, 2*"Variable 2"]
```

Comment: Very nice - +1.

Comment: Very nice indeed.