# Error When Creating Package

Tags: packages

I am trying to make my own package based on the code from this [Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29336/data-table-manipulation-in-mathematica-step-2). The following is the code from that page:

```
BeginPackage["SelectData`"];
select::usage = "select[data,where,condition]";
Begin["`Private`"]

    ClearAll[select, where];
    SetAttributes[where, HoldAll];
    select[table : {colNames_List, rows__List}, w : (where[condition_] | None) : None,
         cols : (columns[varNames__] | All) : All] :=
      With[{namingRules = Dispatch[Thread[colNames -> Thread[Slot[Range[Length[colNames]]]]]]}, 
        With[{cl = {varNames} /. namingRules /. Verbatim[Slot][n_] :> n},
          If[cols === All, #, #[[All, cl]]] &@
            If[w === None,
               {rows},
               (* else *)
               With[{selF = Apply[Function, Hold[condition] /. namingRules]},
                  Select[{rows}, selF @@ # &]
               ]
            ]
        ]
      ]; 

End[]
EndPackage[]
```

Then, on my notebook, use the following data as input:

```
table = List[{"ID", "Variable 1", "Variable 2"}, {"Alpha", 1, 
   0}, {"Beta", 1, 1}, {"Alpha", 0, 0}]
```

Call the package, Needs["SelectData`"]

Evaluating, `select[table, columns["Variable 1"]]`

the output is as follows:

```
select[{{"ID", "Variable 1", "Variable 2"}, {"Alpha", 1, 0}, {"Beta", 
   1, 1}, {"Alpha", 0, 0}}, columns["Variable 1"]]
```

I think I have done something wrong when creating my package, but I can't find it.
Could anyone give me suggestions?

Comment: @b.gatessucks It was typo. I fixed it

Comment: I'd suggest ; after Begin, End and EndPackage.  After package is loaded what does "?select" give?

Comment: Does your function work if its not in the package?

Comment: @Ymareth Using "?select" just returns me the code, not what I define in usage. And Yes, it works when it is not the package.

Comment: Have you set the format of the cell as `Code` or initialize the cell contained your code or just write your package not in a `.nb` file but in a `.m` file at the very beginning?

Comment: @xzczd I write it on .m file at the very beginning

Comment: Did you kill the kernel or restart before executing Needs?

Comment: You have to declare `where` and `columns` also as exported symbols, like `where::usage = ...; columns::usage = ...`. Otherwise, `where` and `columns` are created in ``Private` `` sub-context, and the pattern does not match.

Comment: Sorry one last question.  I assume you wrote this in a notebook (a .nb file) and then did "save as" to a package (.m).  Did you make all the cells of the package initialization cells (in cell properties)? When saving as a package any cell that is not marked as an initialization cell is commented (* *) out.

Comment: @Ymareth Yes I restarted Mathematica.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. However, as is typical, it is recommended to wait about a day before accepting an answer. Other people may come up with better answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. The function `columns` needs to be a public function, instead a private one. This is because you have tried to access it from outside. Thus you should also add a line before begin of Private

   columns::usage = "something"

   Similarly, as @LeonidShifrin and @rasher have mentioned, if you also want to access `where` from outside the package, you should also add

   where::usage = "something"
2. (Minor, but related to a comment) You shouldn't `ClearAll[select]` after the usage information is defined. Otherwise, the usage is no longer kept. That's why `?select` gives the code directly. If you want to clear `select`, move it to before `select::usage`. Also, you don't have to clear `where`, because it is a private variable. There shouldn't be naming conflict unless by purpose.

Comment: ……You mean the only necessary thing here is to add `column::usage = ""` and remove the `ClearAll[select, where];
`?

Comment: Yes. After that the example given by the OP returns some nontrivial results (I haven't read the code and thus don't know the meaning of the return value though.)

Comment: ……Are you sure? I can't fix OP's package by these steps, and even with the `ClearAll` existed, `?select` still gives the desired result. I'm using v8.0.4

Comment: Did you quit the kernel or restart Mathematica after the modifications? Note that the OP used `Needs` to load package. In this method if the package is loaded previously, it is not to be reloaded. You can either use Get (i.e. <<) to load package. In this case you don't need to restart Mathematica when modifications are made in the package.

Comment: +1 - though I think `where` needs the same treatment...

Comment: @rasher Thanks for reminding! `where` doesn't appear in the OP's example. But after a quick look at the code, in general it might be accessed outside. Thus I will add that to the answer.

Comment: I did mention `where` in my comment, which you probably didn't see.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks! Sorry I didn't notice that. Actually your comment already answered the OP's question.

Comment: OK…what I encountered is all because…I didn't notice that you mistyped `columns` as `column` and forgot that the output `?select` should simply be `select[data,where,condition]` rather than the function definition 囧.

Comment: @YiWang I voted for your answer. I missed the  `Clear` part, which actually is a common pitfall, while you didn't. Besides, answering in comments is not a good practice, and I didn't intend mine to be a substitute. I was hoping someone would provide a proper answer, and you did.

Comment: @xzczd : Sorry! Typo corrected.

Comment: I would not suggest defining a blank usage message. If a proper message is not given, then just mention the symbols in question, e.g. `columns; where;`. This is sufficient for the parser to create them in the outer context.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks! Updated.