# Data Table Manipulation in Mathematica 10

Tags: list-manipulation, data, sql

I would like to select columns from a table by column name. I tried the solution described here: [Data Table Manipulation in Mathematica: Step 2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29336/data-table-manipulation-in-mathematica-step-2) . I am using Mathematica 10.

(I would write a comment there, instead of a new question, but StackExchange doesn't let me write comments yet.)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: look at `Association` in mathematica's documentation

Comment: Ah! I realized that I couldn't use the solution described in (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29336/data-table-manipulation-in-mathematica-step-2) because my data was in TableForm.

Comment: Thanks for pointing `Association`, @k_v!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst valid Leonid's code has been superseded by new functionality in Mathematica 10.   As well as Association take a look at the Dataset, Select and Query functions in the help.  But basically try some of the following :

```
data = {{"1", "Cat", "Tiddles"}, {"2", "Dog", "Spot"}};

cols = {"id", "animal", "name"};

(* turns a list of animals into an association and then into a 
 dataset with column headings specified by cols *)

animalsDS = Dataset[AssociationThread[cols -> #] & /@ data]
```

[image: full dataset]

```
(* Just select cats *)

animalsDS[Select[#animal == "Cat" &]]
```

[image: just cat]

```
(* select cats with wildcards *)

animalsDS[Select[StringMatchQ[#"animal", "Ca*" ] &]]

(* selects animals that are cats AND (&&) called tiddles *)

animalsDS[Select[#animal == "Cat" && #name == "Tiddles" &]]

(* selects animals that are cats OR (||) dogs *)

animalsDS[Select[#animal == "Cat" ||  #animal == "Dog" &]]
```