# What is the Mathematica way of joining two tables?

Tags: list-manipulation, data, data-structures

Is there a special *Mathematica* way of joining tables of data together, so that I would get similar functionality as if I was running a database with sql?

For example, I have one particular table here, and getting data out of it is getting a bit verbose. Here is an example, but is there a better way to work with data. I thought there would be a simple way of creating tables and joining them, something similar to a dataframe in R perhaps?

```
Tally[
  Flatten[
    GatherBy[Transpose[{data[[All, 9]], data[[All, 8]]}], # == "Yes"] , 
    1
  ]
]
```

returns

```
(* 
   {
     {{"Yes", "South West"}, 42}, {{"No", "The North"}, 325}, 
     {{"Yes", "Midlands & East Anglia"}, 92}, {{"No", "Scotland"}, 97},
     {{"No", "Midlands & East Anglia"}, 351}, {{"Yes", "Wales"}, 20}, 
     {{"No", "South East"}, 187}, {{"No", "South West"}, 115}, 
     {{"No", "Wales"}, 63}, {{"No", "London"}, 132}, {{"Yes", "London"}, 50},
     {{"Yes", "The North"}, 101}, {{"Yes", "South East"}, 65}, 
     {{"Yes", "Scotland"}, 51}
   }
*)
```

Here is an example of the data I am working with:

```
{{"gender", "age", "maritalStatus", "highestQualification", "nationality", "ethnicity", 
  "grossIncome", "region", "smoke", "amtWeekends", "amtWeekdays", "type"}, 
 {"Female", 51, "Divorced", "Other/Sub Degree", "English", "White", 
  "Unknown", "South West", "Yes", 25, 25, "Packets"}, 
 {"Female", 52, "Married", "No Qualification", "English", "White", 
  "Unknown", "The North", "No", "NA", "NA", ""}, 
 {"Female", 53, "Divorced", "GCSE/O Level", "English", "White", 
  "Unknown", "Midlands & East Anglia", "Yes", 7, 12, "Packets"}, 
 {"Female", 59, "Divorced", "Degree", "Scottish", "White", 
  "Unknown", "Scotland", "No", "NA", "NA", ""}, 
 {"Female", 61, "Married", "A Levels", "English", "White", 
  "Unknown", "Midlands & East Anglia", "No", "NA", "NA", ""},
 {"Male", 66, "Married", "No Qualification", "English", "White", 
  "Unknown", "The North", "No", "NA", "NA", ""}, 
 {"Female", 69, "Widowed", "No Qualification", "English", "White", 
  "Unknown", "Wales", "Yes", 15, 15, "Packets"}, 
 {"Female", 69, "Widowed", "No Qualification", "English", "White", 
  "Unknown", "The North", "No", "NA", "NA", ""}, 
 {"Male", 71, "Divorced", "No Qualification", "English", "White", 
  "Unknown", "The North", "No", "NA", "NA", ""}}
```

Comment: Can you provide the `data`?

Comment: By the way, one obvious mistake / type is that you have  `# == "Yes"`, while a pure function should end with an ampersand : `# == "Yes"&`.

Comment: I've edited above with the data I'm working with.

Comment: And your desired output is..?

Comment: Well, what I was looking for was whether there was an alternative method of working with data in Mathematica, something similar to creating data frames and being able to join tables, or group them in different ways. I am installing R-link now though, so that may solve the productivity issues.

Comment: As [Leonid said](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47601/what-is-the-mathematica-way-of-joining-two-tables#comment141200_47601) Your code works better with `&`: [see here](http://i.imgur.com/fs9ZD0F.png). If that's not the output that you desire edit your question with your desired output. It all depends on what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Normally you use joins when you have more than one table, and you join on some column(s). So, what we'd expect is some minimal example containing 2 such tables, the join call syntax you'd like, and the result you'd expect. Regarding RLink, note that if you plan to transfer large amounts of data back and forth between R and Mathematica, there are a couple of subtleties to make that efficient. I would not write Mathematica off with regards to data table manipulation just yet, though.

Comment: With the data you posted, all you need is: `Tally[Rest@Transpose[{data[[All, 9]], data[[All, 8]]}]]`

Comment: even shorter: `Tally[data[[2 ;;, {9, 8}]]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simulate a generic SQL Group By, here is an option:

Let `data = {{"gender", "age", "maritalStatus"...}...}`

```
d["Data"]=Rest@data;
MapIndexed[(d[#1]=#2[[1]])&,First@data];
```

Now we can use columns names:

```
dataG={#[[1,d@"smoke"]],#[[1,d@"region"]],Mean@#[[All,d@"age"]],Length@#}&/@GatherBy[d["Data"],{#[[d@"smoke"]],#[[d@"region"]]}&];
TableForm[dataG,TableHeadings->{None,{"Smoke","Region","MeanAge","Qtd"}}]
```

[image: tableExample]

If you use these operations frequently (I use a lot), you can look at [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29369/2266), that shows some technics to avoid use `MapIndexed`, and less verbose columns names notation, overloading `Dot` operator.

I believe Mathematica 10 will be much better in this area with the new [Dataset](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) objects. I'll improve this answers a soon I learn how it works.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, If you want to show us a Dataset teaser for this example, be my guess :)

Comment: `Dataset` currently is more geared towards general hierarchical representation of data. Tabular `Dataset`-s are possible, of course. The bigger problem is that the question is not really quite clear to me. As I mentioned in the comment below the question, one needs at least 2 tables for join, and also to specify the type of join (left, right, inner or outer).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general query function you might find helpful in itself or for use as a template for further development.

```
data =
{{"gender", "age", "maritalStatus", "highestQualification", "nationality", "ethnicity", 
  "grossIncome", "region", "smoke", "amtWeekends", "amtWeekdays", "type"}, 
 {"Female", 51, "Divorced", "Other/Sub Degree", "English", "White", 
  "Unknown", "South West", "Yes", 25, 25, "Packets"}, 
 {"Female", 52, "Married", "No Qualification", "English", "White", 
  "Unknown", "The North", "No", "NA", "NA", ""}, 
 {"Female", 53, "Divorced", "GCSE/O Level", "English", "White", 
  "Unknown", "Midlands & East Anglia", "Yes", 7, 12, "Packets"}, 
 {"Female", 59, "Divorced", "Degree", "Scottish", "White", 
  "Unknown", "Scotland", "No", "NA", "NA", ""}, 
 {"Female", 61, "Married", "A Levels", "English", "White", 
  "Unknown", "Midlands & East Anglia", "No", "NA", "NA", ""},
 {"Male", 66, "Married", "No Qualification", "English", "White", 
  "Unknown", "The North", "No", "NA", "NA", ""}, 
 {"Female", 69, "Widowed", "No Qualification", "English", "White", 
  "Unknown", "Wales", "Yes", 15, 15, "Packets"}, 
 {"Female", 69, "Widowed", "No Qualification", "English", "White", 
  "Unknown", "The North", "No", "NA", "NA", ""}, 
 {"Male", 71, "Divorced", "No Qualification", "English", "White", 
  "Unknown", "The North", "No", "NA", "NA", ""}}

queryByFields[data_List, fields : _String ..] :=
  Module[{names, records, rules, columns},
    names = First @ data;
    records = Rest @ data;
    rules = Thread[Rule[names, Range @ Length @ names]];
    columns = {fields} /. rules;
    Tally[Transpose[records[[All, #]] & /@ columns]]]

queryByFields[data, "smoke", "region"]
```

> ```
> {{{"Yes", "South West"}, 1}, {{"No", "The North"}, 4}, 
>  {{"Yes", "Midlands & East Anglia"}, 1}, {{"No", "Scotland"}, 1}, 
>  {{"No", "Midlands & East Anglia"}, 1}, {{"Yes", "Wales"}, 1}}
> ```

```
queryByFields[data, "gender", "smoke", "nationality"]
```

> ```
> {{{"Female", "Yes", "English"}, 3}, {{"Female", "No", "English"}, 3}, 
>  {{"Female", "No", "Scottish"}, 1}, {{"Male", "No", "English"}, 2}}
> ```